# file shared on SMB on zfs on linux cannot be read over network

Tags: zfs, server-message-block

The file can be opened locally.

I think the problem is related to attributes or permissions somehow, but I do not know how to check them.

The files are GoPro videos in a particular directory, and originally were saved onto my MacBook. I transferred them to my Linux machine on a ZFS pool using an `rsync -av --append-verify --info=progress2` command.

Now, with the directory shared from the Linux machine with SMB, neither Windows 10 nor macOS can read these files, although other files in other directories on this share are perfectly readable.

How can I go about troubleshooting this? I can query the file size and it looks right. I'm actually just trying to confirm that all the files are on the zfspool so that I can actually free up the space on my mac's ssd... I'm not confident because of these remaining permissions/attributes related problems.

In particular I'm curious to know how I can fix permissions/attributes within the zfs filesystem so that this sort of thing doesn't keep popping up? I'm not interested in any access control, all of that is done very coarsely with samba users, and I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was `chmod go=r` on the files. They were `-rw-------`.